# Accessing Azure with both Microsoft Account and Work Account

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment

This problem may stem from the dependency on MS accounts for MSDN instead of work accounts, but maybe some one has found a solution?

I use the same email address for both my MS and Work Accounts.

Our Company Subscriptions seems to be linked to our MS Accounts, as does our VSTS accounts. I can sign into Azure Portals using both MS and Work Account. I want to be able to deploy do our company subscription from VSTS.

When I sign into Azure, using my work account, I can see our Azure AD. I am a global admin and can make changes, etc. This is not visible when I sign in using the MS account. It tells me I don't not have access, which I can understand.

In VSTS, I have linked my MS Account to my work account. But I cant access some of the projects @ {whatever}.visualstudio.com VSTS sites with my work account, I must use my MS account.

The main problem is when I try to set up a build and deploy from VSTS into the Company Azure Subscription. To achieve this I need to set up a Service Endpoitn to ARM in Azure. So I go ahead and try to do that.

It fails as it says that the account does not have the sufficient privileges needed in Azure Active Directory. Remember, AAD is only accessible when I log into my work account in the azure portal.

One last point, AAD would see my MS account as a guest account, so I thought 'hey, I will add that account to AAD as a guest and assign privileges necessary to perform the tasks I need'. But because the same email address was used for both my MS account and work account, it tells me when I try to add the guest account, that it already exists.

Is there any way around this problem? How can I associate/move all VSTS subscriptions to my work account?

Answer (score 0):

When the VSTS identity you are using does not have access to the Azure subscription your trying to deploy to, the best way to do this is to create your service endpoint manually.

The steps are [here][1]. See the Azure Resource Manager service endpoint -> Manual subscription definition section. It has a few more steps, but once you create that, just use that service endpoint in your build or release definitions & your good to go.